# Read a particular value xml file and replace values in property file using ant

Tags: java, xml, ant

Suppose I have an xml file like abc.xml
which contains

```
<datasource name="localmysql">
    <inline-jdbc jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                 jdbc-uri="url"
                 jdbc-username="username" jdbc-password="password"/>
</datasource>
<datasource name="localmysqlolap">
    <inline-jdbc jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                 jdbc-uri="url1"
                 jdbc-username="username1" jdbc-password="password1"/>
</datasource>
<datasource name="localmysqltenant">
    <inline-jdbc jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                 jdbc-uri="url2"
                 jdbc-username="username2" jdbc-password="password2"/>
</datasource>
```

**Now I want to read the values of jdbc-uri, jdbc-username, jdbc-password** in node

`datasource name="localmysql"` and change the values of a property file which also contains jdbc-uri, jdbc-username, jdbc-password as keys. Is there a way to do it using ant

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANT replace task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html)
and replace each value. In this case you will need to know old/new properties values.

I used [property regex task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Please remember, that properties in ANT are immutable and can't be modified/updated